# Create Volume on GlusterFS on LES Server

Tags: fuse, openvz, glusterfs

I am using a lowendspirit server and attempting to create a gluster container. Lowendspirt's run as OpenVZ containers.

```
volume create: main: failed: Glusterfs is not supported on brick: [name omitted]:/glusterfs.
Setting extended attributes failed, reason: Operation not permitted.
```

I had my host do the following

```
vzctl set $VEID --devices c:10:229:rw --save
vzctl exec $VEID mknod /dev/fuse c 10 229
```

However, still unable to create.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

```
vzctl set  $VEID --devices c:10:229:rw --save     
vzctl exec $VEID mknod /dev/fuse c 10 229  if not, use:     
vzctl set $VEID --devnodes fuse:rw --save    
vzctl set  $VEID --capability sys_admin:on --save
```

Then

```
vzctl restart $VEID
```